# Dependency errors on installing Banshee

Tags: banshee, dependencies

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 (Verified the ISO hash as well). The VERY first thing I did was open the software centre and try to install banshee. I am met with the following error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
     banshee: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is to be installed
     Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.34.1) but 2.34.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.13-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
     Depends: libsoup-gnome2.4-1 (>= 2.27.4) but 2.40.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.26.1) but 2.40.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.5.0-1 is to be installed
     Depends: mono-runtime (>= 2.10.1) but 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc0.1 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libgconf2.0-cil (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.2-2 is to be installed
     Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.26.4) but 2.26.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libglib2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but 2.12.10-4 is to be installed
     Depends: libgtk2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but 2.12.10-4 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-cairo4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-corlib4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-posix4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-system-core4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 2.10.7) but 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: gnome-icon-theme (>= 2.16) but 3.6.0-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

I should note that the banshee application appears three times when searching for it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ9fj.png

Other applications install fine though.

I installed the latest updates and still received the same error. I even tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but the same thing happened.

Comment: It appears to be bugged, see https://launchpad.net/bugs/1091942.

Comment: It was working for me a week ago, but I had to reinstall Ubuntu due to an unrelated problem. That's when this happened.

Comment: It doesn't look that way... it hasn't been changed since release so it wouldn't have been installable last week either, unless you weren't running 12.10 then.

Answer (score 1):

Banshee is uninstallable due to broken depends. This is because the PPA for Banshee Team has NOT allowed or created a repository for 12.10 yet check this https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/ppa and you will see what I mean.

you can try adding it using `sudo apt-get install banshee`

For those who wish to compile from trunk, add the deb-src line and then run "sudo apt-get build-dep" to install all required dependencies before starting to compile.

see https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/ppa for reference

Comment: It definitely worked for me previously on 12.10 (about a week ago) but after a reinstall, this happened.